# Prove a tensor identity

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, fluid-dynamics, tensor-rank

Prove the tensor identity: $$e_{ij}^2-\frac{1}{3}e_{kk}^{2}=(e_{ij}-\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}e_{kk})^{2}$$

This equality we used it to prove the conservation of energy equation although i don't see clearly how to prove it

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using the "summation convention" that a repeated index is summed-over? And $\delta_{ij}$ is Kronecker delta? And, basically, $e$ is a matrix with entries $e_{ij}$?

Comment: yes we´re using the summation conventionand yep, \delta_{ij} is the Kroenecker delta and yes, e is a matrix with entries e_{ij}

Comment: Expand the right side and write out the sums. You can even get rid of the summations by writing explicitly each term of each summation since the dimension is 3.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Deane ’s comment: expanding R.H.S.

\begin{align*}
(e_{ij} - \frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}e_{kk})^2 &= (e_{ij} - \frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}e_{kk}) (e_{ij} - \frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}e_{kk}) \\
&= e_{ij} e_{ij} - \frac{2}{3}e_{ij}\delta_{ij}e_{kk} + \frac{1}{9} \delta_{ij} \delta_{ij}e_{kk} e_{kk} \\
&= e_{ij}^2 - \frac{2}{3}e_{jj}e_{kk} +  \frac{1}{9} \delta_{jj} e_{kk}^2 \\
&= e_{ij}^2 - \frac{2}{3}e_{kk}e_{kk} +  \frac{1}{9} (3) e_{kk}^2 & (\delta_{jj} = n, n = \text{dimensions})\\
&= e_{ij}^2 - \frac{2}{3}e_{kk}^2 + \frac{1}{3} e_{kk}^2 = e_{ij}^2 - \frac{1}{3}e_{kk}^2\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Why does $e_{jj}e_{kk}=e_{kk}e_{kk}$? One looks to me like $(e_{11}+e_{22}+e_{33})(e_{11}+e_{22}+e_{33})$  and the other looks like $e_{11}^2 + e_{22}^2 +  e_{33}^2$.

Comment: @Keshav This is an abuse on the notation, it is supposed that the same index cannot appear more than twice. Anyway, $e_{jj}e_{kk} = e_{kk}^2 =$ your first expression.

Answer (score 0):

The summation convention works most nicely when you are manipulating multilinear expresions, so you can translate everyting to multilinear terms and work from there. For example, $e_{ij}^2$ is notation for $e_{ij}\delta^{ik}\delta^{jl}e_{kl}$, while $e_{kk}$ really means $e_{kl}\delta^{kl}$ and $e_{kk}^2$ means $e_{kl}\delta^{kl}e_{mn}\delta^{mn}$. With this in mind, write the right hand side $(e_{ij}-\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}e_{kk})^{2}$ as
$$
(e_{ij}-\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}e_{kr}\delta^{kr})\delta^{im}\delta^{jn}
(e_{mn}-\frac{1}{3}\delta_{mn}e_{tu}\delta^{tu})
$$
and see if you can continue from there. Your goal will be to get to
$$
e_{ij}\delta^{ik}\delta^{jl}e_{kl}
-
\frac 1 3 
e_{kl}\delta^{kl}e_{mn}\delta^{mn}.
$$